# Info window when clicking on a marker google maps ap

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the code attached, I'm trying to display some pictures that I have in my database once I click on any of the markers on google maps. Each marker is related to a picture.

My problem relies on the last part of the code, on the las "for" loop. When I console.log(content) I see all my image tags displayed with the correct image url, but when I click on any of the markers I only see the last picture on the array picturesForMarkers. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Javascript

```
var addresses = [];
var picturesForMarkers = [];
var divPictureLatitude = $('.pictures');
$.each(divPictureLatitude, function (i, val) {
    addresses.push(val.children[1].value + ", " + val.children[2].value);
    picturesForMarkers.push(val.children[0].src);

});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addresses[x] + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
    });
}


for (var x = 0; x < picturesForMarkers.length; x++) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
        return function () {
            var content = '<img src="' + picturesForMarkers[x] + '" style="width:300px;">';
            console.log(content)
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, x));
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the [geocoding web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) rather than the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 client geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)?  Note that these geocoding services are subject to a quota and a rate limit, they won't work for more than about 10 addresses at a time without adding error handling and then will be prohibitively slow.

Comment: No, there is no particular reason for that. I'm new to the google maps API so I just tried following someone else's code for the geocoding part and it worked. But what you are saying makes sense, but I will appreciate if you can help me showing me how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `marker` that you're using in the last loop is actually `undefined`, it doesn't have any value due to the fact that you're declaring a new variable `marker` inside the callback of the json call.

I'd try this:

```
var addresses = [];
var picturesForMarkers = [];
var divPictureLatitude = $('.pictures');
$.each(divPictureLatitude, function (i, val) {
    addresses.push(val.children[1].value + ", " + val.children[2].value);
    picturesForMarkers.push(val.children[0].src);

});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var i; // I removed marker.

for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addresses[x] + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
        // The marker has been added to the map, add the event to the marker.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
            return function () {
                var content = '<img src="' + picturesForMarkers[x] + '" style="width:300px;">';
                console.log(content);
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            };
        })(marker, x));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue might be you have only one marker declared. Try creating an array or list of markers and attach image reference to each one of them instead of passing in the only marker variable each time.